# What does "Enter IPSec ID" in vpnc mean?

Tags: linux, vpn

I have been using Cisco client to get connected to a VPN. How do I use that profile to connect by VPN?

I am calling `vpnc` from the CLI. It becomes interactive and asks a few questions. One I don't understand is:

> Enter IPSec ID for : Enter IPSec secret for @:

These two entries – can someone point me to the exact thing it's looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Cisco remote access VPN uses two sets of credentials to authenticate normally.  The first is a group id and password, the second is your user credentials.

openvpn is asking for the group id and password.  Your vpn administrator will be able to provide these.

If this is going to be difficult, you can use the pcf2vpnc script to convert the PCF file that Cisco VPN client uses into something vpnc understands.  Here is a howto:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-setup-cisco-vpn-using-vpnc-ubuntu-jaunty-9-04.html

The PCF file is found in c:\program files\Cisco\Cisco VPN Client\profiles

(or similar depending on your installation)

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by this as I was provided just username and password. The problem might be that Cisco anyconnect seems to be using different protocol than legacy Cisco clients. Install `openconnect` and try

```
openconnect --protocol=anyconnect vpn.your.provider
```

So if you use legacy Cisco protocol, your vpn provider will provide you either with PCF file or with IPSec ID/secret. If your provider wants you using anyconnect, vpnc does not support that protocol.